# This code for webscraping nt wrkng nd giving empty list for Td tags for other tag wrking fine,how to use index i want to hve 4th td tag wid dis clss

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

please get me solution how to get the entity type scrape from this page.This code for web scraping not working and giving empty list for Td tags for other tag its working fine and how to use index i want to have 7th td tag with this class

```
INPUT:import bs4 as bs
import requests as req
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url= "https://portal.unifiedpatents.com/litigation/caselist?case_no=1%3A18-CV-01956"
#driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
a=soup.find_all("td",{"class":"ant-table-row-cell-break-word"})
print(a)
driver.quit()


OUTPUT: "C:\Users\Lumenci 3\PycharmProjects\untitled6\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Lumenci 3/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_2.py"
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Selenium without bs4.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url= "https://portal.unifiedpatents.com/litigation/caselist?case_no=1%3A18-CV-01956"
driver.get(url)
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.ant-table-row-cell-break-word')))
print([element.text for element in elements])
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
['1:18-cv-01956', '2018-12-11', 'Open', 'Delaware District Court', 'Axcess International, Inc.', 'Lenel Systems International, Inc.', 'Infringement', 'NPE (Individual)', 'High-Tech']
```